# remote autocomplete using ajax in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, autocomplete

I'm a newbie to ajax, I got this code from google and now I want to get the data for the input field from database instead of the variable defined `availableTags`. I'm confused that where all I want to change the url to the particular function to run.

This is the url I want to add in order to get the value from database:

```
http://localhost:8888/auto/index.php/birds/get_birds
```

```js
  $( function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
  
    function split( val ) {
      return val.split( /,\s*/ );
    }
    function extractLast( term ) {
      return split( term ).pop();
    }
        function log( message ) {
      $( "<input name='skill'>" ).text( message ).prependTo( "#log" );
      $( "#log" ).scrollTop( 0 );
    }
 
    $( "#tags" )
      // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
      .on( "keydown", function( event ) {
        if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
            $( this ).autocomplete( "instance" ).menu.active ) {
          event.preventDefault();
        }
      })
      .autocomplete({
        minLength: 0,
        source: function( request, response ) {
          // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
          response( $.ui.autocomplete.filter(
            availableTags, extractLast( request.term ) ) );
        },
        focus: function(event, ui) {
        
          $(event).val(ui.item.value);
          // prevent value inserted on focus
          return false;
        },
        select: function( event, ui ) {
          var terms = split( this.value );
          
          if(terms.length <= 3) {
          // remove the current input
          terms.pop();
          // add the selected item
          terms.push( ui.item.value );
          log(ui.item.value);
          if (jQuery.inArray(ui.item.value, availableTags) > -1) {
           availableTags.splice($.inArray(ui.item.value, availableTags), 1);
            //availableTags[jQuery.inArray(ui.item.value, availableTags)] = '';
            terms.push( "" );
            // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
           this.value = terms.join( ", " );
          }
          return false;
          }else{
                var last = terms.pop();
                $(this).val(this.value.substr(0, this.value.length - last.length - 2)); // removes text from input
                $(this).effect("highlight", {}, 1000);
                $(this).attr("style","border: solid 1px red;");
                return false;
            }
        },
        change: function (event, ui) {
            if (!ui.item) {
                $(this).val('');
            }
        }
      });
  } );
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Multiple values</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css"> -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  </head>
<body>
 
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tag programming languages: </label>
  <input id="tags" size="50">
</div>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

**Contoller:**

```
<?Php
class Birds extends CI_Controller{
function index(){
  $this->load->view('birds_view');
   }

function get_birds(){
$this->load->model('bird_model');
if (isset($_GET['term'])){
  $q = strtolower($_GET['term']);
  $data['s']=$this->bird_model->get_bird($q);
}

}
}
```

**Model:**

```
<?php
class Bird_model extends CI_Model{
function get_bird($q){
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->like('bird', $q);
$this->db->order_by('bird','desc');
$query = $this->db->get('birds');
if($query->num_rows() > 0){
  foreach ($query->result_array() as $row){
    $new_row['label']=htmlentities(stripslashes($row['bird']));
    $new_row['value']=htmlentities(stripslashes($row['id']));

    $row_set[] = $new_row; //build an array
  }
  echo json_encode($row_set); //format the array into json data
 }
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace below code of source

```
     source: function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax({
          url: "http://gd.geobytes.com/AutoCompleteCity",
          dataType: "jsonp",
          data: {
            q: request.term
          },
          success: function( data ) {
            response( data );
          }
        });
      },
```

Here `URL` is the path of your json response. Produce a json response in your controller file

```js
  $( function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
  
    function split( val ) {
      return val.split( /,\s*/ );
    }
    function extractLast( term ) {
      return split( term ).pop();
    }
        function log( message ) {
      $( "<input name='skill'>" ).text( message ).prependTo( "#log" );
      $( "#log" ).scrollTop( 0 );
    }
 
    $( "#tags" )
      // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
      .on( "keydown", function( event ) {
        if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
            $( this ).autocomplete( "instance" ).menu.active ) {
          event.preventDefault();
        }
      })
      .autocomplete({
        minLength: 0,
         source: function( request, response ) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://gd.geobytes.com/AutoCompleteCity",
      dataType: "jsonp",
      data: {
        q: request.term
      },
      success: function( data ) {
        response( data );
      }
    });
  },
        focus: function(event, ui) {
        
          $(event).val(ui.item.value);
          // prevent value inserted on focus
          return false;
        },
        select: function( event, ui ) {
          var terms = split( this.value );
          
          if(terms.length <= 3) {
          // remove the current input
          terms.pop();
          // add the selected item
          terms.push( ui.item.value );
          log(ui.item.value);
          if (jQuery.inArray(ui.item.value, availableTags) > -1) {
           availableTags.splice($.inArray(ui.item.value, availableTags), 1);
            //availableTags[jQuery.inArray(ui.item.value, availableTags)] = '';
            terms.push( "" );
            // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
           this.value = terms.join( ", " );
          }
          return false;
          }else{
                var last = terms.pop();
                $(this).val(this.value.substr(0, this.value.length - last.length - 2)); // removes text from input
                $(this).effect("highlight", {}, 1000);
                $(this).attr("style","border: solid 1px red;");
                return false;
            }
        },
        change: function (event, ui) {
            if (!ui.item) {
                $(this).val('');
            }
        }
      });
  } );
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Multiple values</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css"> -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  </head>
<body>
 
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tag programming languages: </label>
  <input id="tags" size="50">
</div>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm using that availableTags variable inside the if condition too. What change I want do over there?

Comment: Please share your controller code of AJAX URL method